# Help with Setting Certain Links to HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an newly installed SSL certificate on my website and
I am trying to figure out how to make some pages point specifically to https and
other point only to http.

For example, if someone is on my website browsing my webpages via https,
and I only need my testimonials and about us page to be http, is this possible?

I know this is possible with hard coding all of the links on the site but I am and already have setup relative links.

Is there a way to maybe add a setting in the .htaccess file that will point the server to http when someone tried to visit my testimonials and about us page?

Comment: The question belongs on serverfault. You should realize that your server does not even *see* the URI until *after* the SSL connection has been made. E.g.: If the URL is `https://yourdomain.com/stuff` then `GET /stuff` is sent encrypted under the SSL layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Page-1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} page-2 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I add that code to my .htaccess file and try to visit my website, it gives me a Internal Server Error (500). I tried visiting the site via http and https but neither one of them worked. Any idea why I might be getting the Internal Server Error?

Comment: Did you have mod_rewrite on in your server, in my answer i remove some lines as they are not related to https. In third and fourth lines page-1 and page-2 are pages you want to redirect to https.

Comment: Yes, I do have mod_rewrite on my server. This still does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php then you can put the following codes in your files.

To Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS:

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
{
   header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

To Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
{
   header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```